# Моментальное изменение ссылки $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, php7

Перевожу сайт на мультиязычность. При загрузке страницы инклудится базовая структура html и код `if (!isset($_GET['lang'])){ $_GET['lang'] = 'ua'; }`, но при этом ссылка не меняется. Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы к ссылке добавлялись значения из $_GET? JS приветствуется.

Comment: С чего бы ей меняться?

Comment: Что ?  Вы про людей или коней ?

Comment: @u_mulder это я просто уточнил, ясно что она не изменится.

Comment: JS History API.  Ну или редирект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените это:

```
if (!isset($_GET['lang'])){ $_GET['lang'] = 'ua'; }
```

Вот так:

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET['lang'] ) ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_GET ) ) {
        header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?lang=ua' );
    } else {
        header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&lang=ua' );
    }
}
```

И получите желаемое.

### Объяснение

`$_GET` - это переменная которая берется из url страницы. Например в `https://adudnik.ru/index.php?test=1` указана `$_GET['test']` со значением `1`

В вашем же случае нужно указать `$_GET['lang']` значение `ua`. Для этого мы делаем редирект пользователя на текущий URL и добавляем к нему `?lang=ua`. По сути перезагружаем страницу с этим параметром.

Однако нам нужно дополнительно проверить есть ли другие $_GET переменные. Если их нет - добавляем `?`, если есть - `&`

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` указывает текущий URL, чтобы пользователь остался на этой странице, а не был выброшен на главную.

Обратите внимание, если вы будете использовать `$_GET` для проверки языка, то у пользователя всё время должен быть lang параметр в юрле. Это очень неудобно. Чтобы этого избежать - используйте куки или сессию.

### Решение с $_COOKIE

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['lang'] ) ) {
    if ( $_GET['lang'] != $_COOKIE['lang'] ) {
        setcookie( "lang", $_GET['lang'] );
        header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
    }
}
if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['lang'] ) ) {
    setcookie( "lang", "ua" );
    header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
}
```

Обратите внимание - куки требуют передачи себя в самом начале запроса. До вывода `<html>` или других параметров header, потому этот код должен стоять в самом начале файла.

В случае с куки - вы должны в дальнейшем получать значение языка для своего кода из переменной `$_COOKIE['lang']` а не из `$_GET['lang']` (т.к. весь смысл этой реализации сводится к тому, чтобы убрать из url значение языка)

Чтобы сменить язык - просто направьте пользователя на нужный ?lang=язык

Файл для тестирования кода на моём сайте: https://adudnik.ru/lang_example.php?lang=ru